# Call multiple functions from one function in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, function

I have three functions that receive no arguments and just return the most recent data from 3 different tables in 3 different schemas.  Each function returns 4 columns of data, all of the same type.  How do I create 1 function that calls all three functions and gives the output of each function?

I tried using Perform "function1"; Perform "function2"; then select * from function3(); roughly speaking and nothing worked.

Comment: Could you please share the code you have? And did you check the manual?

Comment: Your can just UNION the results. `Select * from function1() UNION Select * from function2() UNION Select * from function3();` The preceding removes any duplicates, if keeping them is requires then change to UNION ALL. See [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html).

Comment: Are you writing SQL or PL/SQL?